# IObservable collect all elements in current stream and perform bulk operation

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Example code

```
async Task Main()
{
    var entities = new double[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }.ToObservable();

    entities = Square(entities);
    entities = Print(entities);
    entities = Add(entities, 1);
    entities = await SaveObservable(entities);
    entities = Add(entities, 2);

    await PrintAll(entities);
}

public IObservable<double> Square(IObservable<int> source)
    => source.Select(i => Math.Pow(i, 2.0));

public IObservable<double> Add(IObservable<double> source, double add)
    => source.Select(i => i + add);

public IObservable<T> Print<T>(IObservable<T> source)
    => source.Do(i => Console.WriteLine("Print: {0}", i));

public async Task<IObservable<T>> SaveObservable<T>(IObservable<T> source)
{
    var last = await source.LastOrDefaultAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Collected observable and saving to the db. Last element is '{0}'", last);

    // await database.SaveChangesAsync();

    return source;
}

public async Task PrintAll(IObservable<double> source)
    => await source.ForEachAsync(i => Console.WriteLine("PrintAll: {0}", i));
```

Imagine that in my `SaveObservable` function, I want to perform an operation on the database, e.g. Save all the entities added to a database context in bulk so I can get the database engine (e.g. SQL) to populate any database generated ids.

So what I want this function to do is collect the passed in observable stream, call database.SaveChangesAsync and then essentially carry on by returning the passed in stream.

However if I run the code above, The `Print` function is called again. I do not want any projections/mappings of the observable called previously to run again.

How would I go about achieving this? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm thinking that a pushed based system is not right for what I am trying to achieve. Due to the nature of saving things to the db It should be pulled based.

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await` (Tasks) with observables like that if you want a clean observable pipeline. Observables are inherently async so just stick with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your comment is spot on: this is probably best done with plain-old, pull-based programming.

As for your code you have two problems going on:

1) Observables are like item pipelines. Your code essentially sets up two pipelines:

```
entities -> Square -> Print -> Add(1) -> SaveObservable
entities -> Square -> Print -> Add(1) -> Add(2) -> PrintAll
```

This is why you see `Print` called twice. If you want to see it called once, you probably want the pipelines to do something like this:

```
entities -> Square -> Print -> Add(1) -> SaveObservable
                                     \-> Add(2) -> PrintAll
```

2) However, that's easier said then done, thanks to the mixture of `async` and `IObservable`. The lazy way to make a multi-casted pipeline is to slap a `.Publish().RefCount()` after the Add call:

```
entities = Square(entities);
entities = Print(entities);
var entitiesAdded = Add(entities, 1).Publish().RefCount();
var _ = await SaveObservable(entitiesAdded);
entities = Add(entitiesAdded, 2);

await PrintAll(entities);
```

This doesn't work though, because `Publish` makes the observable is hot, and once it is used in `SaveObservable`, the items don't emit again. Another way around is `.Publish()` followed by a `.Connect()` when all the children are connected, but that doesn't play well with `await`.

The way that will work for your code is to add `.Replay().RefCount()`, but it may not perform well, because Rx has to set up an internal buffer that holds all items for the life of the subscription.

```
var entities = new double[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }.ToObservable();

entities = Square(entities);
entities = Print(entities);
entities = Add(entities, 1).Replay().RefCount();
entities = await SaveObservable(entities);
entities = Add(entities, 2);

await PrintAll(entities);
```

For more information about Hot/Cold observables, `Publish`, `Connect`, `Replay`, and `RefCount`, [see here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect).

In summary though: I suggest you use EF and TPL without Rx.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and breakdown. I'm experimenting with rx and as much as I love the push-based model I think I need to stop trying to apply it everywhere!

Comment: I don't think your explanation is 100% correct. Essentially it is right, but the cause of the two subscriptions is the `SaveObservable` method itself. The `await source.LastOrDefaultAsync()` causes a subscription and the `return source` ultimately does too. This pipeline is fixed by avoiding the `await source.LastOrDefaultAsync()`. Using `.Replay().RefCount()` is not the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have two subscriptions is due to these two lines:

1. `var last = await source.LastOrDefaultAsync();`
2. `await source.ForEachAsync(i => Console.WriteLine("PrintAll: {0}", i));`

Both cause a subscription to your original source observable.

The first is effectively:

```
var last = await
    new double[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(i => Math.Pow(i, 2.0))
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine("Print: {0}", i))
        .Select(i => i + 1)
        .LastOrDefaultAsync();
```

The second is effectively:

```
await
    new double[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(i => Math.Pow(i, 2.0))
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine("Print: {0}", i))
        .Select(i => i + 1)
        .Select(i => i + 2)
        .ForEachAsync(i => Console.WriteLine("PrintAll: {0}", i));
```

The answer to this problem is to avoid any of the `async`/`await` code. Rx handles all the sync work far better than TPL does anyway.

You can also `await` an observable without involving tasks.

Perhaps try your code this way:

```
async void Main()
{
    var entities = new double[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }.ToObservable();

    entities = Square(entities);
    entities = Print(entities);
    entities = Add(entities, 1);
    entities = SaveObservable(entities);
    entities = Add(entities, 2);

    await PrintAll(entities);
}

public IObservable<double> Square(IObservable<double> source)
    => source.Select(i => Math.Pow(i, 2.0));

public IObservable<double> Add(IObservable<double> source, double add)
    => source.Select(i => i + add);

public IObservable<T> Print<T>(IObservable<T> source)
    => source.Do(i => Console.WriteLine("Print: {0}", i));

public IObservable<T> SaveObservable<T>(IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
    {
        var last = default(T);
        return 
            source
                .Do(
                    t => last = t,
                    () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Collected observable and saving to the db. Last element is '{0}'", last);
                    })
                .Subscribe(o);
    });
}

public IObservable<double> PrintAll(IObservable<double> source)
    => source.Do(i => Console.WriteLine("PrintAll: {0}", i));
```

This works and produces the following output:

```
Print: 1
PrintAll: 4
Print: 4
PrintAll: 7
Print: 16
PrintAll: 19
Print: 64
PrintAll: 67
Print: 256
PrintAll: 259
Print: 1024
PrintAll: 1027
Collected observable and saving to the db. Last element is '1025'
```

---

To allow the `SaveObservable` to complete before continuing with the pipeline you need to add a `.ToArray()` to that method. That changes the `IObservable<T>` that produces zero or more values to a `IObservable<T[]>` that produces one array with zero or more elements. Thus it must complete all of the values before it moves on.

Try changing `SaveObservable` to:

```
public IObservable<T> SaveObservable<T>(IObservable<T> source)
{
    return
        source
            .ToArray()
            .Do(ts =>
            {
                var last = ts.Last();
                Console.WriteLine("Collected observable and saving to the db. Last element is '{0}'", last);
            })
            .SelectMany(t => t);
}
```

That now outputs:

```
Print: 1
Print: 4
Print: 16
Print: 64
Print: 256
Print: 1024
Collected observable and saving to the db. Last element is '1025'
PrintAll: 4
PrintAll: 7
PrintAll: 19
PrintAll: 67
PrintAll: 259
PrintAll: 1027
```

---

The code is now effectively this:

```
await
    new double[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(i => Math.Pow(i, 2.0))
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine("Print: {0}", i))
        .Select(i => i + 1)
        .ToArray()
        .Do(ts =>
        {
            var last = ts.Last();
            Console.WriteLine("Collected observable and saving to the db. Last element is '{0}'", last);
        })
        .SelectMany(t => t)
        .Select(i => i + 2)
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine("PrintAll: {0}", i));
```

Comment: The issue I have is that I don't want the pipeline after `SaveObservable` to run until `SaveObservable` has finished. Since I need to bulk create/update/delete things in the db at that point.

Comment: That's easy. Just put a `.ToArray()` after the `SaveObservable`. Otherwise it can't work the way you want it to. I'll put up a sample tomorrow of how this works.